# How would we classify it when an adult developed a neurocognitive disorder leading to learning disability?

Tags: abnormal-psychology

Quote from DSM-5:

> C. Onset of intellectual and adaptive deficits during the developmental period 
> (Page 33: Diagnostic criteria for Intellectual Disability [Intellectual Development Disorder]).
>
> **[...]** In acquired forms, the onset may be abrupt following an illness such as meningitis or encephalitis or head trauma occurring during the developmental period.
> (Page 38: Development and Course)

Comment: Welcome to Psychology.SE. Can you please provide more information on what you don't quite understand from what you have read?  Also, when quoting, please can you be more specific on **where** you are quoting from, espectially when quotes concern different pages and different context.

Comment: When looking at the DSM, Page 40 also states *"Intellectual disability is categorized as a neurodevelopmental
disorder and is distinct from the neurocognitive disorders, which are
characterized by a loss of cognitive functioning. Major neurocognitive disorder may co-occur
with intellectual disability (e.g., an individual with Down syndrome who develops
Alzheimer's disease, or an individual with intellectual disability who loses further cognitive
capacity following a head injury). In such cases, the diagnoses of intellectual disability
and neurocognitive disorder may both be given."*

Comment: Also, directly after the quote from Page 38, it states *"When intellectual disability results from a loss of previously
acquired cognitive skills, as in severe traumatic brain injury, the diagnoses of intellectual
disability and of a neurocognitive disorder may both be assigned."*

Comment: What I have a doubt on is what it would be classified as when an adult develops a neurocognitive disorder leading to a learning disability. It would be diagnosed as a neurocognitive disorder, but what label would they use to explain the intellectual disability, because I.D. can only be developed during the developmental period?